# Extracting data from godaddy using jsoup

Tags: java, html, parsing, jsoup

I'm using Jsoup to extract html from Godaddy's website. I want to extract this specific segment below. I have both the final webpage's specific segment, where it states "Sorry, google.com is taken" and the HTML code itself.
[image: This is the specific section of the webpage.]
[image]

However in my program I have the following:

```
import java.io.IOException;
```

import org.jsoup.Jsoup;

```
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Element;
import org.jsoup.select.Elements;

public class test {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        String url = "https://www.godaddy.com/dpp/find?checkAvail=1&tmskey=&domainToCheck=google";
        Document document = Jsoup.connect(url).get();
        Element div = document.getElementById("searchResults");
        Elements spans = div.select("span");
        for (Element e: spans)
            System.out.println(e.text());
    }
}
```

However, this code prints a NullPointerException. I know that JSoup cannot work with JS, but this is HTML and for some reason it is not being extracted. I also tried extracting all the HTML from the page and it does not contain these words.

Can anyone point me in the right direction or give me another way to extract this piece of information from godaddy?

Comment: Use the Godaddy API - https://developer.godaddy.com/

Comment: @PedroLobito Will do thank you.

Answer (score 0):

First of all the url you have provided redirects to some other location so you will need to follow redirects:

```
Document document = Jsoup.connect(url).followRedirects(true).get()
```

But even that will not fix your problem. To show if a domain is available or not the website uses javascript to fetch data from the server. Now this request will fail since this is coming from a unknown origin.

In short *Pedro* is right you have to use the API.

Comment: Could you possibly point me in a direction on how to use this Godaddy API? I'd like to be able to incorporate it into Java.

Comment: godaddy provides REST api, so you have learn what they are and how to use them in JAVA. https://www.mkyong.com/webservices/jax-rs/restfull-java-client-with-java-net-url/